# Ejecutar funciones desde un diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

me preguntaba si seria posible ejecutar una función si esta esta diccionario, como los Diccionarios con acciones de C#
digamos que tenemos el siguiente diccionario:

```
acciones = {
"hola":hola(),
"adios":adios()
}
```

tenemos la string `a = "hola jeremías"`
y la dividimos con el método `split()` tal que así 'a.split(' ')'
quedaría un array con 'hola' y 'jeremías'
hay alguna forma de saber si array[0] = 'hola' esta en 'acciones' y si es así que ejecute la función que acompaña a 'hola' en el diccionario quedaría algo así:

```
def hola(cadena:str): print(cadena)

acciones = {"hola":hola()}

a = "hola jeremías"
acion, _ = split(' ')
#que hago para ejecutar la función del diccionario si es que acion esta en el diccionario
```

referencia de C#:

```
Dictionary<string, Action<Nombre_Clase, String>> Acciones;
Acciones.Add("hola", Acciones_CS.hola)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las funciones son objetos en Python; puedes almacenarlos en un diccionario, pasarlos como parámetros, etc.

Debes tener presente que:

```
funcion()
```

es una invocación a la función: la función se ejecuta y retorna un resultado, mientras que

```
funcion
```

es la función misma, no se resultado.

#### Demo

Tenemos tres funciones, que reciben cadenas y retornan una versión convertida de ellas:

```
def mayusculas(cadena:str):
    return cadena.upper()

def exclamación(cadena:str):
    return f"{cadena}!"

def pregunta(cadena:str):
    return f"¿{cadena}?"
```

Con eso ya podemos armar el diccionario:

```
acciones = {
    "mayusculas": mayusculas,
    "exclamación": exclamación,
    "pregunta": pregunta
}
```

Nuevamente, se usa el **nombre** de la función, pues queremos almacenar su código. (En realidad sólo guardamos una referencia al código, pero el efecto es el mismo).

Luego, por cada frase recibida, la dividimos usando `split` y usamos el primer resultado como llave del diccionario. Esto nos devuelve la función, que a continuación ejecutamos.

```
tests = [
    "mayusculas aviso",
    "exclamación rebajado",
    "pregunta cuantos artículos desea"
]

for test in tests:
    accion, objeto = test.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
    funcion = acciones[accion]
    resultado = funcion(objeto)
    print(resultado)
```

produce:

```
AVISO
rebajado!
¿cuantos artículos desea?

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Esta idea surge de un pequeño interprete escrito en C# que usando este método es capaz de "mejorarse" por si solo, ya que podría añadir las variables de otro diccionario a 'acciones' verdad?

Comment: @ANONIMO. Obvio; es un diccionario y puedes agregar, modificar y eliminar entradas.